# Get the touched area

Tags: android

I'd like to know if there's a way to get the size or the limits of a touched area ? So for instance, it could give me how many pixel the finger is covering.

In fact the same question has been posted here for the Ipad : 
[iPad: Measure/detect covered area by a finger touch on screen (NOT only touch coordinates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316358/ipad-measure-detect-covered-area-by-a-finger-touch-on-screen-not-only-touch-coo)

I think it will depend also of which type of screen android is running on.

So I'd like to know if it is possible under android ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [`MotionEvent#getSize(int)`](http://d.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getSize(int))