# MotionEvent multiple touch events get mixed up and influence each other (see demo video)

Tags: android, events, multi-touch, android-2.1-eclair

**Purpose of the app:**

A simple app that draws a circle for every touch recognised on the screen and follows the touch events. On a 'high pressure reading' `getPressure (int pointerIndex)` the colour of the circle will change and the radius will increase. Additionally the touch ID with `getPointerId (int pointerIndex)`, x- and y-coordinates and pressure are shown next to the finger touch.

Following a code snipplet of the important part (please forgive me it is not the nicest code ;) I know)

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){

    //draw circle only when finger(s) is on screen and moves 
    if(iTouchAction == (MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)){
        int x,y;
        float pressure;

        //Draw circle for every touch
        for (int i = 0; i < touchEvent.getPointerCount(); i++){
            x = (int)touchEvent.getX(i);
            y = (int)touchEvent.getY(i);
            pressure = touchEvent.getPressure(i);

            //High pressure
            if (pressure > 0.25){
                canvas.drawCircle(x, y, z+30, pressureColor);
                canvas.drawText(""+touchEvent.getPointerId(i)+"  | "+x+"/"+y, x+90, y-80, touchColor);
                canvas.drawText(""+pressure, x+90, y-55, pressureColor);
            }else{ //normal touch event 
                canvas.drawCircle(x, y, z, touchColor);
                canvas.drawText(""+touchEvent.getPointerId(i)+" | "+x+"/"+y, x+60, y-50, touchColor);
                canvas.drawText(""+pressure, x+60, y-25, pressureColor);
            }
        }           
    }
}
```

**The problem:**

A HTC Desire running Android 2.1 is the test platform. The app works fine and tracks two finger without a problem. But it seems that the two touch points interfere with each other when they get t0o close -- it looks like they circles 'snap'to a shared x and y axle. Sometimes they even swap the input coordinates of the other touch event. Another problem is that even though `getPressure (int pointerIndex)` refers to an PointerID both touch event have the same pressure reading.

As this is all a bit abstract, find a video here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bFxjFexrclU

**My question:**

1. Is my code just simply wrong?
2. Does Android 2.1 not handle the touch events well enough get things mixed up?
3. Is this a hardware problem and has nothing to do with 1) and 2)?

Thank you for answers and/or relinks to other thread (sorry could find one that address this problem).

Chris

Comment: I've definitely seen that before. I think it's probably just 2.1 not playing nicely with multitouch. Try your code on a 2.2 phone if you can.

Comment: Thanks for this Falmarri!!! It seems that there hardware is also an issue. This video compares the Google Nexus One and the Samsung Galaxy S and the latter does not have any troubles with the a similar app to mine! http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hVlsRCMltDg&feature=player_embedded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hate to tell you this, but it's your hardware.

The touch panel used in the Nexus One (which I believe is the same hardware used in the HTC Desire) is known for this particular artifact. We did some work to alleviate the "jumps to other finger's axis" problem around the ACTION_POINTER_UP/DOWN events for Android 2.2 by dropping some detectable bad events, but the problem still persists when the pointers get close along one axis. This panel is also known for randomly reversing X and Y coordinate data; two points (x0, y0) and (x1, y1) become (x0, y1) and (x1, y0). Sadly there's only so much you can do when the "real" data is gone by the time Android itself gets hold of it.

This isn't the only panel in the wild that has dodgy multitouch capabilities. To tell at runtime if you have a screen capable of precise multitouch data reporting without issues like this, use PackageManager to check for [`FEATURE_TOUCHSCREEN_MULTITOUCH_DISTINCT`](http://d.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#FEATURE_TOUCHSCREEN_MULTITOUCH_DISTINCT). If you don't have this feature available you can still do simple things like scale gestures reliably.

Comment: Wow Adamp, thanks for a lot it was my suspicion too, when I saw other video with similar problems! Will check 'FEATURE_TOUCHSCREEN_MULTITOUCH_DISTINCT'for my available devices. I was wondering how to find out about the hardware platform and its multitouch capabilities without buying the actually device?! For the research project I am working on we haven't decided on actual platform. The Android system has the 'getPressure (int pointerIndex)' but has trouble with multitouch -- iOS products have good multitouch capabilities but no public API to read the pseudo pressure on the screen? Thoughts?

Comment: see this link for pseudo pressure reading for the iPHone: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316358/ipad-measure-detect-covered-area-by-a-finger-touch-on-screen-not-only-touch-coo

Answer (score 1):

Anyone tried **[this fix for multitouch gestures](http://code.google.com/p/android-multitouch-controller/)** on older androids before? I am planning to evaluate it for [my own project](https://github.com/Philzen/WebView-MultiTouch-Polyfill), as it also deals with android 1.x/2.x buggy multitouch.

Luke seems to have covered the problem described here as well as other common touch input problems on pre-3.x devices.

Hope it helps, Cheers.