# iOS size of navigation bar back button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I am creating a taller navigation bar, height == 200, however, when i clicked below the back button, it also navigates back.

[image]

here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;

    navBar = [[SRNavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, 200.0)];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
    [self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:YES];

    __weak id weakSelf = self;
    self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = weakSelf;

[self styleNavBar];
}

- (void)styleNavBar
{
    UINavigationItem *newItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc]initWithTitle:[[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"nickName"]];

    UIBarButtonItem *menu = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(back)];
    newItem.leftBarButtonItem = menu;
    newItem.leftBarButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:245/255.0 green:124/255.0 blue:0/255.0 alpha:1];

    [navBar setItems:@[newItem]];

    [self.view addSubview:navBar];
}

- (void)back
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

you can use custom button giving height as per your need

```
-(void)addLeftButton
{
     UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_back.png"];

     UIButton *aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

     [aButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

     aButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, buttonImage.size.width, 200.0);

     UIBarButtonItem *aBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:aButton];

     [aButton addTarget:self action:nil forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

     [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:aBarButtonItem];
}
```

Comment: I just want to navigate back when I click exactly on the image, not anywhere below. My question is, why does it navigate back when i even click below it?

Comment: Then add a fix height to it so  that it wont effect on below part of button

Comment: no it won't work. I checked the view hierarchy, the button frame is exactly what i want, but still, the entire area below it is still clickable

Answer (score 0):

Apple Support:

> I recommend that you avoid having touch-sensitive UI in such close
>   proximity to the nav bar or toolbar. These areas are typically known
>   as "slop factors" making it easier for users to perform touch events
>   on buttons without the difficulty of performing precision touches.
>   This is also the case for UIButtons for example.
>
> But if you want to capture the touch event before the navigation bar
>   or toolbar receives it, you can subclass UIWindow and override:
>   -(void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event;

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9719364/2138564