# Why the UITextField of navigationItem custom title view get focused when touch outside of its bounds?

Tags: uitextfield, uitouch

I have a UITextFields on the navigationitem custom titleview. When I touch it's out right side, it's get focused too.  I test the situation in the hittest method. Here is the data.

```
hitbounds field point: {269, 6.5}, bounds:{{0, 0}, {255, 35}}; searchView point: {59, 6.5}, bounds: {{0, 0}, {45, 35}}; searchButton: {58, 11}, bounds: {{0, 0}, {44, 44}}
```

Field view contain a searchview in the right who contain a search button.

field point: {269, 6.5}, bounds:{{0, 0}, {255, 35}};
The point is not in its bounds clearly. But The field get foucsed and the keyboard appears.

And eventually I find when the keyboard appear, the methods even not are called `pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event  hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`

Why?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got a clue from [Why does UINavigationBar steal touch events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079907/why-does-uinavigationbar-steal-touch-events/39249392#39249392)

I guess navigation bar steal touch event and dispatch the touch event to textfield directly.

So Here is the solution. It works well.

```
@implementation UINavigationBar(Xxxxxx)

- (UIView*)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UIView *v = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    return v == self ? nil: v;
}

@end
```