# navigation bar shows after hiding it in viewwillappear

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

Hidden the navigation bar in ViewWillAppear

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }
```

but when clicking on top of the viewcontroller navigationbar shows up.
Did anyone faced this issue ?

Comment: hide it on ViewDidAppear ?

Comment: @KKRocks its getting hidden initially,but on tapping top of the viewcontroller navigation bar showing again

Comment: it is another problem ...put that which is related to this issue

Comment: Can't produce the same behavior. Can you produce the same behavior in a ___Sample Project___ and upload it somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Solved issue, need to disable the barHideOnTapGestureRecognizer property cause of slop area on the UINavigationBar, link for answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/37595538/3282447

Answer (score 0):

I dont know this one is correct or not. But its working fine for me.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) 
{
  super.viewWillAppear(animated)
  self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
  self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
}
```

Comment: its hiding initially, but once i click on top of viewcontroller, navigation bar showing.

Comment: Check your entire code because navigation bar enabled somewhere of the class otherwise  Could you please provide your class files or project. Then only I would be able to find the solution.

Comment: Solved the issue by disabling the barHideOnTapGestureRecognizer property, thanks for your time.