# Is there any way at all that I can tell how which areas of the screen is being pressed

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

For example, if someone put their hand on an iPad screen, is there anyway to shade in the areas of the hand so you see a hand print?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can detect where the finger-tips are using the `-[UITouch locationInView:]` method, but you can't get the outline of the whole hand. The iPad cannot sense this.

Comment: There is a private API that will give you the approximate size of the touch.  Using it will get you rejected from the app store.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103447/is-there-any-way-at-all-that-i-can-tell-how-hard-the-screen-is-being-pressed

Comment: @robmayoff: Yes, but that's still a property of the fingers, not the whole hand.