# Touch sensitivity in iPad, how to get value using Cocoa Touch/Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

I know Apple in GarageBand made a piano keyboard supporting touch sensitivity: GarageBand detects the intensity of user touches on the screen.

How can I implement or use this feature?

Comment: Current hardware doesn't support touch sensitivity. Apple did the trick with the accelerometer's help.

Comment: +1 @Costique - even Jobs mentioned when he was presenting GarageBand for iPad that the accelerometer detects how hard you hit the screen

Comment: It is strange, because when iPad on the table it is also working

Comment: Lying on a table doesn't exclude vibration caused by touches.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any way at all that I can tell how hard the screen is being pressed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103447/is-there-any-way-at-all-that-i-can-tell-how-hard-the-screen-is-being-pressed)

Comment: If by "touch sensitivity" you mean pressure, you can't do it.  If by "touch sensitivity" you mean touch size, there is no public API but there is a private API (which will exclude you from the app store).  See the "possible duplicate" link above.

Comment: @Robmayoff, touch size would be nice! Can someone show me an example on how to get touch size (width, height)? Thanks!