# Getting biometric information from stylus for iPad

Tags: ipad, biometrics, jot-touch-sdk

Using a stylus such as Jot Touch or Pogo Connect, how do I get biometric information such as coordinates (X,Y) pressure (T), stroke speed (S) when a user signs on the iPad (using Objective-C)?

Which method or libraries should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iOS SDK provides X/Y coordinates.  It does not provide access to stroke speed or pressure.

`UIPanGestureRecognizer` computes a velocity, presumably simply by taking distance / time.  Possibly it computes a moving average of distance/time.  You can do that yourself.

The [Jot Touch SDK](https://github.com/Adonit/JotTouchSDK) provides access to pressure data if you are using a Jot Touch.

The [Pogo Manager SDK](http://www.tenonedesign.com/t1pogomanager.php) provides access to pressure data if you are using a Pogo Connect.

If you want to support both styli, you will have to use both SDKs.

If you don't want to put your app in the App Store, [you can use a private API to determine the touch size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2103715/77567) (which may be a good proxy for pressure).

Comment: woah!!! thanks man, gonna check the SDK of both and the post that you shared gonna check

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the Jot Touch or Pogo API's?  There are no Apple methods or libraries for this.  Its 3rd party hardware.  Apple does not have support for pressure.  You can use the touchesBegan: and touchesMoved: functions to get x,y data on a touch and then calculate speed.  You can also use gesture recognizers to detect movement and speed.

Comment: thanks for the response gonna check gesture recognizers methods for obtaining speed as you suggest :)